# servo acting weirdly

Tags: servo

I have bought two original TowerPro MG966R 360 degree continuos rotation Hi-torq digital servos.

Expected results :

- 90       deg -- no rotation
- 90 - 0   deg -- speeding up to one side
- 90 - 180 deg -- speeding up to the other side

Real results :

- When I am sending 50-90 degrees PWM, they behave like standard (non-continuos) servos and turn in 50-90 degree angle.
- Bellow 50 there is small speedup, then continuos rotation at max speed to one side.
- Above 90 there is continuos rotation at max speed to the other side.

I am using standard Arduino Servo library,
servo has external 2A power and
all grounds (servo, arduino, power) are connected together.

Both new servos behave same, so I assume fault is on my side (software).
Same code and wiring works fine with other (cheap,copycat) servo I have.

May I ask for some pointer to what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

My test code :

```
    // 9 - servo pin
    // 2 - pot pin
    
    #include <Servo.h>

    Servo srv;

    void setup(){
        srv.attach(9);
    }
    void loop(){
        //~ srv.write(map(analogRead(2),0,1023,50,90));
        srv.write(map(analogRead(2),0,1023,0,180));
        delay(10);
    }
```

Bought here : [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/TowerPro-MG996R-Digital-Robotic-Continue-Servo-RoHS-with-360-Rotation/253678010093)

Manufacturer page : [here](https://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg995-robot-servo-360-180-rotation/)

Comment: there is no reason to use the `map` function or the `analogRead` function ... use minimal code when debugging

Comment: What @jsotola said, and: you are updating the servo signal at a higher rate than its normal PWM frequency of 50Hz; anything could happen. Try a longer delay.

Comment: Ok, thanks for corrections .. I've tried simpler code and longer delays (20,50,2000) but it didn't help - same result.

Comment: Hm. Weird. Also weird: the Towerpro MG966R product video at the bottom of this page: http://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg995-robot-servo-360-180-rotation/ shows about the same behaviour you describe, but I can't imagine these servos in the video are "working as intended" if they are supposed to be continuous rotation servos.

Comment: I've contacted manufacturer and linked this question

Comment: looks like a soft start function of some kind

Comment: @Jirka-Justra: Any answers yet from the manufacturer?

Comment: Guy e-mailed me 'I will get back to you' .. so I am currently on hold.

Comment: update : I've send kind reminder; response was that they arrange replacement for me .. hmm - interesting, but ok with me so far

Comment: update : I've got new set .. it rotate both side and continuously, but speed is constant :/ ... will communicate with them more - build quality is great as usual